# Input Current for Basic Chopper DC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-down

I have a very basic question about the input current in a basic DC chopper. Following is a picture taken from the book "Power Electronics for Technology", by Ashfaq Ahmed.

[image]

Considering that the switch is ideal, then the power loss during the switching operation is zero and \$V_{\text{o}}I_{\text{o}} = V_{\text{i}}I_{\text{i}}\$. I understand that the input RMS current is the same as the output rms current, however, when I calculate the output RMS voltage and use \$V_{\text{o}}I_{\text{o}} = V_{\text{i}}I_{\text{i}}\$ to determine the output current, the values found are different.

Example: $$V_{\text{RMS}} = V_{\text{i}} \times \sqrt{d}$$ $$ I_{\text{RMS}} = \frac{V_{\text{RMS}}}{R}$$

Input voltage = 100 V, Load = \$10 \Omega\$, duty cycle = 0.4. The output voltage and RMS current are 63.25 V and 6.33 A, respectively. However, the input RMS current calculated by \$V_{\text{o}}I_{\text{o}} = V_{\text{i}}I_{\text{i}}\$ gives 4A.

What am I missing?

Comment: If Vi=Vo and Ii=Io, then you probably switched Io with Ii, or similar. If Vi=100, then Vo=100, automatically, and if Io=10, then Ii must be 10, too. How did you calculate it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I calculate using the formulas "Vrms = Vi * sqrt (d)", "Irms = Vrms / R" and "VoIo = ViIi".

Comment: Yes, you said that in your question, I meant how did you "unpack" the ViIi=VoIo relation. At any rate, when you calculated Vrms=f(Vi), you automatically calculated Vrms=f(Vo); same for Ii and Io.

Comment: I dont know if I'm doing the right way. The VoIo = ViIi relationship described in the book involves averages voltages and currents. To apply VoIo = ViIi, I simply considered that the input rms voltage is 100V. And I used the voltage and current output rms encountered by other formulas.

Comment: My question is if I'm using the VoIo = ViIi relationship in the wrong way.